# How can I toggle display from none to table-cell?

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I have a half-working script below. The only issue is the parent element also disappears after hovering out. I also can't get a fade-in/out to work.

Any ideas?

html

```
 <div class="group mt10">
     <div class='col2 pull-left homeTile' style="margin-right:10px;">
         <a class='homeHover' title="Weddings" href='#' style="background-image:url(../img/wedding-cake.jpg);">
             <span>Weddings</span>
         </a>
     </div>
     <div class='col2 pull-left homeTile'>
         <a class='homeHover' title="Weddings" href='#' style="background-image:url(../img/wedding-cake.jpg);">
             <span>Weddings</span>
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {  

     $('.homeHover').css("display", "table" );    

     $('.homeHover').hover(function() { 

         $(this).find('span').stop().toggle().css("display", "table-cell" ); 
     },  
     function(){ 

         $(this).find('span').stop().toggle().css("display", "none" ); 
     });      
  });          
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a fade-in/out in the code you posted so I can't address that.

Given what you did post, would take out `.stop()` and `.toggle()` because it's not clear what those functions are supposed to be doing from the code you posted and use `visibility` which hides the element but the element still takes up space in the document layout.:

```
$('.homeHover').hover(
     function () {
         $(this).find('span').css("visibility", "visible");
     },
    function () {
         $(this).find('span').css("visibility", "hidden");
     }
 );
```

[Visibility Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/7Hn2s/1/)

If you want to stick with `display` which completely removes the element from the document layout, you need to give the `a` element some dimensions so the `a` element won't completely disappear (technically the `a` is still there, it just has nothing in it now so you don't see anything):

```
$('.homeHover').hover(
     function () {
        $(this).find('span').css("display", "table");
     },
     function () {
         $(this).find('span').css("display", "none");
     }
 );
```

(just used `100px` as an example):

```
.homeHover {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[Display Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/7Hn2s/2/)